# Null response instead huge JSON in Laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project written in Laravel 5.6 and I need to return a huge JSON (close to 5MB). It contains two keys: hasMore (bool) and data (rendered view). I debugged it (via dd()) and everything works fine until return. Browser sees this answer as blank. Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hard to tell without any of your code really. Maybe not return but echo the response? Post what you have

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post my code, because its production on one site :(